# how can I properly invoke a google cloud function inside another function

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I am trying to invoke a function (http triggered) in a function as follows:

```
exports.myFunction = async (req, res) => {
   rp(settings); //request-promise library; calling myFunction
   await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 5000));
   res.send()
}
```

I feel this is not a good approach, my considerations are:

- I am not waiting for rp to complete because I do not need the
  response from it.
- I am awaiting 5 seconds in order to insure the request was fired.

is there a better approach?